# Archiver for macOs that support file modifications in preview

Tags: macos, archiving, password-protection

I am a new macOS user and trying to get the same (or find alternatives) stack that I had on the previous platform.

Here is my question: Is there any archiver app available that could open zipped password-protected txt files in the preview, allowing me to edit the same file and update the archive on file save?

I know there are plenty of different apps that allow you to open protected archives and open files in the preview, but I haven't found yet one that supports edit.

Comment: Software recommendations are offtopic. Ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: I'll answer this once it's migrated.